# Equation with modulo n and primes

Tags: ring-theory

I have the next problem: find $n\geq2$ such that the equation $x^2-x+\hat2=\hat0$ has only one solution in $\mathbb Z n$.

Let $a$ be the only solution of the equation.We get that $\hat1-a$ is also a solution so $a=\hat1-a$ , $\hat2a=\hat1$. $a={\hat2}^{-1}$ results that ${\hat2}^{-2}-{\hat2}^{-1}+\hat2=0$ so $\hat7=0$.

I think that $n$ can be any multiple of $7$, but on the solution is written only that $n=7$. Is somewhere a condition that $n$ needs to be prime?

Comment: You should check that it does not work for the strict multiples of 7. In Z$/7kZ$, $k$ greater than $2$, you have a priori several candidates for the solution : the $4 + 7l$, $0 \leq l \leq k-1$. For instance in $Z/14Z$ you have 2 solutions : 4 and 11. If it is not precised that n must be prime, you must make all the vérifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misinterpreted the relation you obtain: $7\equiv 0\mod n$ means $n$ is a *divisor* of $7$. As $7$ is prime, this implies $n=1$ (excluded by hypothesis, and uninteresting anyway). So the solution is $n=7$.

Comment: How can you get that 2 has an inverse?

Comment: That's because $2$ is not divisible by $7$, and $7$ is a prime number.

Comment: But you have to use that before in Zn , before knowing that n=7.

Comment: $\hat2a=\hat1$, $a={\hat2}^{-1}$ I am not sure about this